# Is it worth mentioning to a potential employer that you have used their products before?

Tags: interviewing

I understand that if it's something that is incredibly common, it would be of little value to mention this. For instance if you're interviewing with Samsung and you say "I have a Samsung phone" that means practically nothing because so many people have Samsung phones.

In my case, I have an interview with a company that makes electrical connectors. I have designed several circuits boards that utilize their connectors and have been very pleased with their quality. Is this something that would be worth mentioning to the interviewer? I feel like this would be a good way to express interest in the company, as well as show that I'm experienced with that area of work. But on the other hand, I feel like employers might just think "yeah, that's what everybody we interview says" and completely dismiss it.

Comment: If you can explain why you think their product is significantly different and better from their competition -- if there's a problem they solved for you that others couldn't -- that might show you had some insight into the market. If it's just "yeah, I've never had any complaints", that's not exactly a ringing endorsement of them, or of your depth of knowledge/interest, and might be better held back.

Comment: Really? So you have actual real of the product and wonder it that would be of value?  -1

Comment: "I have designed several circuits boards that utilize their connectors and have been very pleased with their quality." - Rather than emphasizing the quality (which is not relevant), emphasize your experience, something like "I have experience using your company's connectors in several circuit board designs that I did".

Answer (score 22):

I would mention it but not stress it. Showing familiarity with one of their products in a positive light cannot hurt you at all.

You don't have to praise it, saying something like 'I use it because it's a good solid product at a price I can afford' is fine. Going overboard would just look fake.

Whether it would make a difference to you getting the job is another matter, but you never know, it might be the deciding factor if all else was equal.

Comment: Also depends on the product and position. For example, Stack Exchange loves hiring people from the community (especially for community managers) because they already understand the community. Other products it might not be as important.

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin `Stack Exchange loves hiring people from the community (especially for community managers)` that *used* to be the case.

Answer (score 11):

If they ask you in such a way that you can answer it in that way, such as "Why do you think you are a good fit?" or "Why apply here?" or "Where did you hear of us before?", then go for it. But don't go out of your way or change topics to mention that, it will seem ingenuine.

Comment: +1 That would be the best time to work it in.  Also for "Why do you want to work for us?" or "What do you know about our company".

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you have a connection with the potential employer is something to work into the cover letter.

While I wouldn't make a big deal out of trivial connection, but if that connection is a reason why you became interested in the opportunity you should mention it.

The cover letter is the perfect place to mention this because that is where you highlight information that isn't in the resume or isn't obvious in the resume.

If you are past that stage, then think of several places you could mention this connection one time during the interview. You don't want to work it into all your answers, but not mentioning it at all would be skipping an opportunity to highlight your case.

Answer (score 2):

You've already worked with this company's product, and you know it and like it? **Yes, YES, you *should* mention this!** You have a fantastic opportunity here, one that other applicants might not have. Don't waste it!

Spend a minute imagining that you are the interviewer rather than the interviewee. All things being equal, who would *you* rather hire? Someone who will have to spend days or weeks learning the product--and might even come to realize that they dislike the way you do things? Or someone who has already worked with the product enough that they can hit the ground running on day one, excited and knowledgeable?

All things being equal, when choosing between two similarly qualified candidates, there's not a company in the world that wouldn't prefer to hire this second choice! It'll save them time, money, and hassle.

And remember, your interviewer doesn't just want to know that you'll be good for the job. She'll also want to make sure that you will *stay* on the job! Turnover is a beeyotch, and it's extremely common nowadays. If someone isn't a good fit, they won't last long.

Mentioning that you know and love the product, then, will be a *huge* feather in your cap. Because it doesn't just say why you would be a great fit for her company: it also speaks to why *it* might be a particularly great fit for *you.* If you *already* know and love the product, that means you won't be as likely to walk off the job the moment some other offer for $0.35 more an hour comes your way.

It also hints at a more pleasant and productive work environment, for you and your whole team. *You* won't be some Negative Nancy, constantly butting heads and demanding they change course. You'll be a *Helpful Harriett*, someone who clearly likes the voyage they're already on! And that doesn't mean you're just "along for the ride," either. But it *does* mean that when seas get choppy, you'll be more likely to help steady the rudder than to abandon ship.

This kind of "fit" is so important to companies that they are far more likely to hire someone who is a "good fit" over someone with a theoretically great resume. And this is true even if your position isn't at the core of what they do--e.g. if you are applying to this company as an accountant or a salesman rather than someone who will literally be building the circuits.

Now, I agree with other comments on here that you shouldn't just say nice things about their circuits as a weird non sequitur. Don't show up at the interview and say, "Hi! My name is Chris and by the way if you change your circuits I'll *KILL MYSELF!*" And don't assume that giving a glowing review of their product will do *all* the heavy lifting during the interview process.

But during that interview, several opportunities to bring up your knowledge and appreciation for their product will arise naturally, as part of the discussion. *Take one!*

And when you do, make sure to talk about their product in a way that reveals your knowledge of it, not just your appreciation of it. This will separate you from the fakers and the haters.

It's not enough to clinch the job, but it will be enough to help you stick out from the pack. At the very least, it will make you sound eager to impress, and that's rarely a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really important, but it you're able to describe how and why you use/prefer there product, it can add to your level of expertise. You could also indicate why there product is better for certain projects or situations. You could contrast it with other products that made projects more difficult or due to inferior quality, required more maintenance.

Not all products have fans. You never know, you could be tapping into an aspect of their marketing they didn't think of. In the US, there are many people who are extremely loyal to car brands and take please in hating others and buy stickers, hats and t-shirts displaying that.